# Can't change column type in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, constraints, alter, bigint

While trying to alter the column type from int to bigint,

```
alter table MSDAT_ARCH.dbo.NAME_OF_PK_COLUMN alter column ARME_NR bigint
```

mssql throws an error:

```
The object STD_XXX depends on column object NAME_OF_PK_COLUMN
```

The background is, that the primary key is a user defined type with a user defined standard value.

When I try to drop it, mssql tells me that it is not a constraint.

I managed to alter the column type simply to int, but how can I drop the default value, which infact is used by other tables, too?

The table contains 1.7 Billion rows, so simply dropping and re-creating is not my favourite option :-)

Comment: Post the actual schema, not a verbal description of the schema. What statements did you try to alter the type? What does a default value have to do with changing a column's type?

Comment: I have edited the original post an added the alter table statement. I don't know either the connection between a default value and the column type. And I could change the type from a user defined type to int.

Comment: And the schema. You mention default values and constraints that don't appear here. You *have* to post any constraints, foreign keys, indexes, or primary keys that use this column if you want an answer about them

Comment: Nonetheless, can you post db fragment schema?

Comment: Sorry, how can I do that? :-)